# Analysing the order of arrivals using a permutation test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, biostatistics, permutation-test

I have data on the arrival times of bird species to bird feeders. I'm interested in asking the question 'does species identity affect arrival order'

In R my data look something like this:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="Order speciesA speciesB speciesC speciesD speciesE
 absent           10          12         5           3         1  
 first            12          1         22           3         2  
 second            3          12         3           5         3  
 third            14          1          4          15         3  
 fourth            5          13         1           4         2  
 fifth             2          5          2           5         11 
             ") 
df
```

so species A arrived first 12 times, second 3 times etc.

When I knew the population size in a theoretical model I could run a chi-squared test for first arrivals ([How to analyse animal arrival times to food](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197901/how-to-analyse-animal-arrival-times-to-food)).

But I'm thinking for this data, something like a permutation test would be more appropriate. Am I along the right track in looking at permutation tests?

Thanks

EDIT: I should emphasise that the raw data that generate the above table look like the following:

```
bird-feeder# speciesA speciesB speciesC speciesD speciesE
        1           1        2        3        4        5
        2           2        1        4        3        5
        3           2        3        4        1        5
        4           1        2        3        5        4
        5           1        3        4        2        5
```

where the numbers under the species columns correspond to arrival order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an answer in Kendall's Coefficient of Concordance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_W

If I view the bird feeders as judges (the nomencalature for this test) then it makes sense.

Although there is an issue if there are missing data and I'm not sure how to deal with that yet.